# inject into unit test (only XML)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, junit

Want to inject a dao that has a configured data source injected into it.. not a fan of annotation because it makes code ugly, i want a pure XML solution.

the test cases are in subfolders in test folder, which is at the same level as the src folder

```
src
   com
       name
           dao
               ProductDao
test
   com
       name
           dao
               ProductDaoTest
```

ProductDaoTest needs to have ProductDao injected in it. tried to do that, spring injects it ok, but the ProductDao depenedencies arenot being injected, and I am facing NPE.

thought about moving test classes into src folder, but I dont think I should have to do that. the other alternative that I am thinking of is running the test cases via the browse through controller calls (but wont be unit testing anymore), so I am stuck trying to figure out the right thing to do.

thank you!
p.s. tests are junit, tomcat, spring 3.1

Comment: @downvoter, care to share some of your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What methods in the DAO do you want to unit test? Are you not actually trying to test the DB connectivity?

Otherwise I agree with @duffymo.

**Edit**: To elaborate a bit, try to adapt the following code chunk to your test class needs:

```
final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext beanFactory = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "applicationContext.xml" );
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = beanFactory.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBeanProperties( this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE , true );
ProductDao dao = context.getBean( "productDao" );
```

and see if that doesn't do the trick for the Dao dependency beans.

Cheers,

Comment: But is there a reason you have the beanFactory final?

Comment: Habit, there is no reason for it to be mutable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have to do that.  You just need to make the application context available to the test and ask it to wire them appropriately.